# Establish relation between node and gmap marker

Tags: 7, google-maps

I have a gmap module (https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) view that serves the map of locations. I also have a list of those locations under the map. I need to establish a relationship - a class, a rel attribute, or something like this, based on the node id, so that when I click the marker, the correct element in the list can be identified.

I tried adding identification to the marker objects so that they can be related to the list items on click. I have tried the `hook_gmap()` and the theming preprocess functions to add an attribute to the markers and failed.

I have also tried to hook into the Google Maps marker events, but could not do it without overriding the native infobubble events, which I don't want to override.

The actual question:

How can I pass information to markers created with GMap, so that they can be aware of the node id? Some html attribute like class or rel would be ideal. Adding it as a part of icon image path, like image.jpg?nid=1111 would also do the trick.

Comment: What module are you using to create the markers?

Comment: I use a gmap module.

Comment: Notice that you are simply stated facts, without asking any explicit questions. What is exactly that you don't understand in the task you described?

Comment: Clarified the question. Getting an impression that this question in the context of the GMap module may not be solvable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use this module to create views related to your nodes to create gmap with markers:

https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc

Comment: Thank you for your response DarkeK. I am aware that there are limited ways to pass the data to markers in other setups. I would prefer to not rebuild the complete functionality though, if there is a way it can be made with GMap.